Displaying images reactively
Please assist with the means of displaying images on the shiny app reactively.
But first I struggled even displaying a single image
Tried the following
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
SelectInput(inputId = "images", label = image),
mainPanel( 
image output(image))

Server <- function(input,output){
output$image
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

I get the error that goes "No handler registered for type
The code as mentioned leads to an error and reading the images are stored as raster data an cannot work with it like that

Look at the help page for ?imageOutput and specifically look at the example to get an idea of how it should work. You should have an imageOutput somewhere in your UI and a renderImage() somewhere in your server function. It's not clear from what you've shared exactly what you have stored in your variables. What exactly are your "images"? Are they actual image data? Are they paths to images at different URLs? Are they local files on your computer?

I'm uncertain where the problem might be. It shows a broken image file with no specified errors

The two functions where used, after I a few iterations these lines seemed to get the job done.
image <- list( image1 = "image1.png",
                image2 = "image2.png",
                image3 = "image3.png")

ui<- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout 
sidebarPanel( 
         selectInput(inputId= "select", label = "Select Image", choices =c(image1, image2, image3), selected = image1)),
mainPanel(
textOutput("selection")
imageOutput("img"))))
server<- function(input,output){
reactive_data <- reactive({
selected_image = input$select
return (selected_image)
})

output$selection <- renderText(
reactiv_data())

output$img<- renderImage(
image_path <- image[[input$select]]
list(src = image_path, alt= "Alt text",
  width = "50%", height = "50%")
}, deleteFile = FALSE)}

shinyApp(ui, server)

